# Multiple sheets object error in vba code

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, copy-paste

I am having an issue with a "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error.  My if then statement is not recognizing one of the objects being compared  please help me to understand what I am doing wrong.

```
Sub Enter_deposits()

    Sheets("Deposits").Activate

    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer


    For x = 4 To 21
        For y = 10 To 500
            If Sheets("deposits").Range(2, 4).Value = Sheets((Cells(x, 14).Value)).Range(y, 2).Value _
                    And Sheets((Cells(x, 14).Value)).Range(y - 1, 3) = 0 _
                    And Sheets("deposits").Range(x, 15).Value <> Sheets((Cells(x, 14).Value)).Range(y, 3) Then

                Sheets("deposits").Range(x, 15).Copy
                Sheets((Cells(x, 14).Value)).Range(y, 3).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

            Else

            End If
        Next y
    Next x
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to understand how the range-object and cell-object work in VBA. If you, for example, want to reference to the value in cell `"D2"` in the "Deposits"-sheet, you can do this with either:

```
Sheets("deposits").Range("D2").value
```

or

```
Sheets("deposits").Cells(2,4).value
```

It seems like you are mixing up the use of these two objects in you code.